# Difference between isinstance and type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I was looking at some code on the web, and I saw some code I'm not used to. The one that most called my attention was:

```
if not isinstance(string, str):
    #dosomething
```

What would be the difference if I did instead:

```
if type(string)!=str:
    #dosomething
```

Comment: General suggestion: when you have a python question use the python tag.  If the question is specific to python-3.x use both tags.  That should increase the number of viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check out all the great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python).

[type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) simply returns the type of an object.  Whereas, [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

Returns true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

Example:

```
class MyString(str):
    pass

my_str = MyString()
if type(my_str) == 'str':
    print 'I hope this prints'
else:
    print 'cannot check subclasses'
if isinstance(my_str, str):
    print 'definitely prints'
```

Prints:

```
cannot check subclasses
definitely prints
```

Comment: Feel free to comment on why you would downvote.